How to apply the capitalize with condition?
I'm wondering how to use the capitalize function when another column has a specific value.
For example, I want to change the first letter of students with Master's degree.
# importing pandas as pd 
import pandas as pd 

# creating a dataframe 
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'A': ['john', 'bODAY', 'minA', 'peter', 'nicky'], 
    'B': ['Masters', 'Graduate', 'Graduate', 'Masters', 'Graduate'], 
    'C': [27, 23, 21, 23, 24]
})

# Expected result
#   A   B   C
#0  John    Masters 27
#1  bODAY   Graduate    23
#2  minA    Graduate    21
#3  Peter   Masters 23
#4  nicky   Graduate    24

I tried it like this, but it didn't apply well.
df[df['B']=='Masters']['A'].str = df[df['B']=='Masters']['A'].str.capitalize()


You showed us your expected result but we haven't seen your actual result.

Because it returned the same result as the original df. (i.e., no changes)

Can you assign to the .str attribute?

@JohnGordon Sorry, but can you clarify it? Do I need to change the .str.capitalize()?

Here is the complete code:
import pandas as pd 

# Creating the DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'A': ['john', 'bODAY', 'minA', 'peter', 'nicky'], 
    'B': ['Masters', 'Graduate', 'Graduate', 'Masters', 'Graduate'], 
    'C': [27, 23, 21, 23, 24]
})

# Capitalize column A conditionally based on B
df['A'] = df.apply(lambda row: row['A'].capitalize() if row['B'] == 'Masters' else row['A'], axis=1)

# Display the updated DataFrame
print(df)

Output:
     A         B   C
0   John   Masters  27
1  bODAY  Graduate  23
2   minA  Graduate  21
3  Peter   Masters  23
4  nicky  Graduate  24


Although it seems like the ChatGPT code, thank you for your comment.

You want to use df.loc for this:
m = df['B'] == 'Masters'

df.loc[m, 'A'] = df.loc[m, 'A'].str.capitalize()

Output:
       A         B   C
0   John   Masters  27
1  bODAY  Graduate  23
2   minA  Graduate  21
3  Peter   Masters  23
4  nicky  Graduate  24

Alternatively, use Series.mask:
df['A'] = df['A'].mask(m, df['A'].str.capitalize())

Or use Series.where with the inverse condition (~m):
df['A'] = df['A'].where(~m, df['A'].str.capitalize())

